# VS CODE ON WSL LINUX DISTRIBUTION

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to install vs code on WSL Linux to be able to open editor from terminal but I keep receiving this message "To use Visual Studio Code with Windows Subsystem for Linux I must install VS Code in Windows and uninstall the Linux version in WSL I did the former but don't know how to uninstall the latter" is there anyone that can help me out would greatly appreciate it thanks.

Comment: I am telling my experience that I have installed wsl and added ubuntu and in my vs code(windows) I have installed Remote WSL from that I can use my vs code in WSL with full features and can open a remote window. This is my personal experience, if you find it useful you can go for it

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below command in wsl

```
sudo apt-get remove code
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you already ran `$ sudo apt remove code` and found that it didn't produce the result desired.

##### Here is the deal, and you will find that this is a pretty general consensus:

You need to either navigate through the Apt Package Managers files, and find what ever it is that is in there that windows is still seeing, or you can just remove your WSL instance of Linux, followed by a re-install of Linux.

##### I suggest the reinstall.

You should never save sensitive data or info using a WSL Linux distro, so there shouldn't be any reason why this isn't feasible. Also, in your situation, which is a WSL/Microsoft situation, you need to keep your Windows overlord happy, therefore; maintaining a healthy, consistent Linux operating system is not your goal. The purpose of WSL is to offer the end-user access to a Linux shell while running the Windows 10/11 OS. You shouldn't be using it as a file system, unless you need to use an EXT4 file system for a particular reason.

Just reinstall the WSL Linux distro (also I suggest Debian for WSL, things will work smoother if use it rather than the other distros).